# Exclude image formats from Files directive in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, regex

Apologies if this question is too simple or in the wrong place but I want to `noindex` everything but image files on the server. I'm using WordPress as a headless CMS, yet some images are being sourced directly from my server and I still want them indexed, while everything else, I don't need indexed.

I've experimented with the following but my syntax is wrong or semantically I'm breaking some rules:

```
#<Files ~ "\.(?!png|jpe?g|gif)$">
#    Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
#</Files>

#<FilesMatch ".+\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
#</FilesMatch>
```

As it's currently set up, everything is set to noindex. *How do I exclude image formats?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression matches files ending with `.gif`, `.jpg`, `.jpeg` & `.png`, but you need a regular expression that matches everything but them. This is possible with a *negative lookahead* regular expression. From Jan Goyvaerts' [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

> Negative lookahead is indispensable if you want to match something not
> followed by something else. When explaining [character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), this
> tutorial explained why you cannot use a negated character class to
> match a `q` not followed by a `u`. Negative lookahead provides the
> solution: `q(?!u)`. The negative lookahead construct is the pair of
> parentheses, with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark
> and an exclamation point. Inside the lookahead, we have the trivial
> regex `u`.

So here, you'd replace the `u` with your `.*\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$`, resulting in something like:

```
<FilesMatch "^(?!.*\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$).*$">
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
</FilesMatch>
```